# Getting "EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property" error when I delete a users custom field

Tags: 7, entities

I have added extra fields to the user object.
One of the fields I have added was a Skype text field to hold the user's Skype contact information.
The field had a machine name:
 `field_contact_information_skype`

Recently we decided to get rid of this field.
After deleting it through the admin UI ( *admin/config/people/accounts/fields* ) I was no longer able to save a user after editing.
If I did so I would get an error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_contact_information_skype. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 354 of /home/master/public_html/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

If I go back and add a new text field to the user object and the text field I am adding has the same machine name then I can edit and save a user object (through the Drupal user edit page) without this error happening.

Should I be able to add fields to the user object and delete those fields without unexpected results like this?
Does anyone know how I can fix this so I can get rid of that Skype field?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I think you call `entity_metadata_wrapper` somewhere in your code like `$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);` so first search in your codebase for `field_contact_information_skype`

Comment: it maybe like `$wrapper->field_contact_information_skype`

Comment: Hi berramou, thanks for responding.  This is just a field that I have added to my user object at some point in the past and I no longer need it.  I don't reference the fields anywhere in any code of mine, and if I delete the field then it causes this error.